# BaseX XML database in C++ encoding issue

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I work with Base X and try to integrate a XML database with c++ on Windows 7. I use the BaseXclient API from https://github.com/JohnLeM/BasexCPPAPI/
it contains the pugixml parser and uses the boost lib. I got it to work but I have issues with the encoding. The xml dokuments in my database are utf-8 and contain some letters and symbols that are not displayed correctly on console output(like ä and °).

I set the console code page with chcp 65001.
I changed the locale with std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); in c++ and when I cout these letters and symbols directly in my Programm and not from the database they are displayed correctly. The database output also changed but is still wrong.

I also set the pugi parser with pugi::xml_encoding::encoding_utf8; but the database output is not affected. here is a code example from the string list interface:

```
virtual ~my_string_list_interface() {};

my_string_list_interface(const std::string& DBHOST, const std::string& DBPORT, const std::string& DBUSER,const std::string& DBPASSWD)  : base_type(DBHOST,DBPORT,DBUSER,DBPASSWD) {};
virtual my_string_list get(string query,int stage){

    my_string_list my_string_list_;
    pugi::xml_encoding::encoding_auto;
    pugi::xml_parse_result parse_;
    pugi::xml_document doc;

    string results = session().execute("XQUERY "+query);

    parse_ = doc.load(results.c_str());

    pugi::xpath_node_set is = doc.select_nodes("/record/mid");
```

The API uses boost streambuf to get the data. The code from boost streambuf looks like that:

```
    std::string read_streambuffer(){return read_streambuffer(response_);};
    std::string read_streambuffer(boost::asio::streambuf & response)
    {

        std::string results;
        boost::system::error_code error;

        boost::asio::streambuf::const_buffers_type bufs = response.data();

        std::size_t size(0);
        std::string line;
        auto ptr_b = boost::asio::buffers_begin(bufs);
        for(; ptr_b != boost::asio::buffers_end(bufs); ++ptr_b, ++ size) 
        {if  (*ptr_b != 0) {line.push_back(*ptr_b);} else if (size > 1) break; };


        response.consume(size);
        return line;

    };
```

Is there a way to specify the encoding for the buffer stream or string? I use a string list for the database output. should I use wstring or is there something i missed? 
Thanks!

Comment: At least the whole `read_streambuffer` could (should) be [`return { buffers_begin(response.data()), buffers_end(response.data()) };`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4df80362a14573a)

Comment: Thanks but that did not work for me. I found a simple solution and just used std::replace(results.begin(), results.end(), '¤', 'ä'); for every different symbol. Its not the best solution but it worked.